# RadioButton & Checked Attribute

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

The checked attribute is not applied , the condition returns true, but radio button doesn't get checked.

i am trying to set one of the radio buttons checked , based on my model values.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="float-right">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="td-radio">
                    <input id="Voiture_IsTrajetSimple" name="Voiture_TypeTrajet" type="radio"                                                                                 
                        <% var KMVoiture_IsTrajetSimple = Model.KMVoiture_IsTrajetSimple;
                           if (KMVoiture_IsTrajetSimple)
                           {%>
                        checked
                        <% } %>>
                    <label class="label-radio" for="Voiture_IsTrajetSimple">Trajet simple</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="float-right">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="td-radio">
                    <input id="Voiture_IsTrajetAR" name="Voiture_TypeTrajet" type="radio" 
                        <% var KMVoiture_IsTrajetAR = Model.KMVoiture_IsTrajetAR;
                           if (KMVoiture_IsTrajetAR)
                           {%>
                        checked
                        <% } %>>
                    <label class="label-radio" for="Voiture_IsTrajetAR">Trajet A/R</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: I don't understand what is the question?

Comment: MVC 4 , the question is, why it is not working , what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Using Razor syntax (which you are not using) it would be as simple as `checked="@Model.KMVoiture_IsTrajetAR"` ([reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/))

Comment: What is the HTML that arrives in the browser, for your code?

Comment: @HansKesting im not using Razor, everything comes in except Checked attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is strange, i have fixed the problem just by getting the value directly from the model , without using a variable, like that :

```
                <input id="Voiture_IsTrajetSimple" name="Voiture_TypeTrajet" type="radio"                                                                                 
                    <%if (Model.KMVoiture_IsTrajetSimple)
                       {%>
                    checked
                    <% } %>>
                <label class="label-radio" for="Voiture_IsTrajetSimple">Trajet simple</label>
```

and it worked :/ .

Answer (score 1):

In your code all inputs are missing value property it needs to something like:

```
<input id="Voiture_IsTrajetSimple" name="Voiture_TypeTrajet" type="radio"  value="TrajetSimple">
<input id="Voiture_IsTrajetAR" name="Voiture_TypeTrajet" type="radio" value="TrajetAR">
```

For this to work your model has to have `Voiture.TypeTrajet` property with type that could be set to `"TrajetSimple"/"TrajetAR"` values (for example a string or an enum). Once any of radio-buttons is checked on client value of `Voiture.TypeTrajet` will be set to the correspondingly.

So the solution could be:

1. Create an enum with all the possible values for your KMVoitureTrajet property

   ```
   public enum TypeTrajetEnum 
   {  
      Simple,
      AR   
    }
   ```
2. In your model create a `KMVoitureTrajet` property (instead of `KMVoiture_IsTrajetAR` and `KMVoiture_IsTrajetSimple` boolean properties that you currently have)

   ```
   public class Model
   {
       public TypeTrajetEnum KMVoitureTrajet{get;set;}
   }
   ```
3. In the view you can render radio-buttons by using [Html.RadioButtonFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.radiobuttonfor(v=vs.118).aspx) helper:

   ```
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.KMVoitureTrajet, TypeTrajetEnum.Simple ) Trajet simple
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.KMVoitureTrajet, TypeTrajetEnum.AR )Trajet A/R
   ```
4. In the controller action that returns a view you can pre-select a value by setting:

   ```
   var model = new Model{
        KMVoitureTrajet = TypeTrajetEnum.AR
   };
   return View(model);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<div class="float-right">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-radio">
                  <% var KMVoiture_IsTrajetSimple = Model.KMVoiture_IsTrajetSimple;
                       if (KMVoiture_IsTrajetSimple)
                       { %>
                         <input id="Voiture_IsTrajetSimple" name="Voiture_TypeTrajet" type="radio" checked = "checked"/>
                    <% } else { %>
                         <input id="Voiture_IsTrajetSimple" name="Voiture_TypeTrajet" type="radio" />
                      <% } %>
                <label class="label-radio" for="Voiture_IsTrajetSimple">Trajet simple</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<div class="float-right">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-radio">
                <% var KMVoiture_IsTrajetAR = Model.KMVoiture_IsTrajetAR;
                   if (KMVoiture_IsTrajetAR)
                   { %>    
                       <input id="Voiture_IsTrajetAR" name="Voiture_TypeTrajet" type="radio" checked = "checked"/>
                <% } else { %>
                         <input id="Voiture_IsTrajetAR" name="Voiture_TypeTrajet" type="radio" />
                      <% } %>
                <label class="label-radio" for="Voiture_IsTrajetAR">Trajet A/R</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: in that case , the inputs won't be rendred !

Comment: It is getting rendered on my end like this only. Any errors showing up in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use this?

```
<input id="Voiture_IsTrajetSimple" name="Voiture_TypeTrajet" 
    type="radio" <%= Model.KMVoiture_IsTrajetSimple ? "checked" : "" %> >
```